# Gcloud ai-platform, can't create model with own prediction-class

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I try following AI Platform [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/notebooks/scikit-learn/custom-prediction-routine-scikit-learn.ipynb#scrollTo=ToGeA0Htssrl) to upload a model and a prediction routine but one part fail and I don't understand why.

My prediction class is the same as in their tutorial:

```
%%writefile predictor.py
import os
import pickle

import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.externals import joblib

class MyPredictor(object):
  def __init__(self, model, preprocessor):
    self._model = model
    self._preprocessor = preprocessor
    self._class_names = load_iris().target_names

  def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):
    inputs = np.asarray(instances)
    preprocessed_inputs = self._preprocessor.preprocess(inputs)
    if kwargs.get('probabilities'):
      probabilities = self._model.predict_proba(preprocessed_inputs)
      return probabilities.tolist()
    else:
      outputs = self._model.predict(preprocessed_inputs)
      return [self._class_names[class_num] for class_num in outputs]

  @classmethod
  def from_path(cls, model_dir):
    model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'model.joblib')
    model = joblib.load(model_path)

    preprocessor_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'preprocessor.pkl')
    with open(preprocessor_path, 'rb') as f:
      preprocessor = pickle.load(f)

    return cls(model, preprocessor)
```

the code I use to create my model in cloud is:

```
! gcloud beta ai-platform versions create {VERSION_NAME} \
  --model {MODEL_NAME} \
  --runtime-version 1.13 \
  --python-version 3.5 \
  --origin gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/custom_prediction_routine_tutorial/model/ \
  --package-uris gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/custom_prediction_routine_tutorial/my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz \
  --prediction-class predictor.MyPredictor
```

But I end up with such an odd error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Unexpected error when loading the model: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128) (Error code: 0)"
```

The thing is that when I run the same command without the:

```
--prediction-class predictor.MyPredictor
```

it work fine.

Does someone know the reason of this ? I think `model.joblib` might have an encoding problem but when I load it myself there is nothing wrong

Comment: Repeated the steps in the tutorial and can confirm there is an issue in the tutorial. 

Created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/issues/419

Comment: @Hadrien Berthier can you retry again ?

Comment: I've manage to make it work, the problem was that in the tutorial they use pickle for the preprocessor and Joblib for the model, you need to use Joblib for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find the solution,

In the tutorial they use pickle to save the preprocessor object created, and Joblib to save the model.

You need to use Joblib to save both and then send it to google storage.